# Understanding the usage of ln

Tags: ln

From coreutils' manual, for `ln`

> ln makes links between files. By default, it makes hard links; with
>   the -s option, it makes symbolic (or soft) links. Synopses:
>
> ```
> ln [option]... [-T] target linkname
> ln [option]... target
> ln [option]... target... directory
> ln [option]... -t directory target...
> ```
>
> • If two file names are given, ln creates a link to the first file
>   from the second.
>
> • If one target is given, ln creates a link to that file in the
>   current directory.
>
> • **If the --target-directory (-t) option is given, or failing that if
>   the last file is a directory and the --no-target-directory (-T) option
>   is not given, ln creates a link to each target file in the specified
>   directory, using the targets’ names.**

What does the part in bold mean?

in particular 
 what do the followings mean

- "failing that if the last file is a directory"
- "using the targets’ names"?

Thanks.

Comment: It means that if you to `ln /path/to/files/* /path/to/some/directory/` or `ln -t /path/to/some/directory/ /path/to/files/*`, a link to each of the files matching `/path/to/files/*`will be created in `/path/to/some/directory/` with identical names to the originals.

Comment: @DopeGhoti:  You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 8):

It means that if you to `ln /path/to/files/* /path/to/some/directory/` or `ln -t /path/to/some/directory/ /path/to/files/*`, a link to each of the files matching `/path/to/files/*` will be created in `/path/to/some/directory/` with identical names to the originals.

Comment: thanks. what does 'failing' mean?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/95379

Comment: Essentially it's 'else'. *If the -t option is given, or failing that if...* means *If the -t option is given, else if...*

Comment: As a word of warning, related to the use of relative path names, you can't go to '/path/to/files' and type 'ln * /path/to/some/directory/' b/c that will just give you a self loop in the target directory of every filename to itself.

Answer (score 6):

I think 
http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln

makes it clearer. You have these forms:

1. ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME (1st form)
2. ln [OPTION]... TARGET (2nd form)
3. ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY (3rd form)
4. ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET... (4th form)

and

```
-t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
specify the DIRECTORY in which to create the links
-T, --no-target-directory
treat LINK_NAME as a normal file
```

`-T` says that if you pass two arguments, you absolutely mean form 1 (second arg is the link_name), not 3 -- in other words, you want to make sure you haven't accidentally passed a directory as the second argument.

Example:

```
mkdir output
ln -s /etc/passwd output #OK passwd link goes into output/passwd
```

vs

```
mkdir output
ln -sT /etc/passwd output #FAIL; output is already taken and is a directory
```

Link `-t`, is the opposite of `-T`. It expects whatever comes after it to be a directory to put links into, which allows you to do things like:

```
list_link_targets | xargs -d '\n' ln -s -t directory
```

which would be much more challenging to do with the 3rd form.

Comment: thanks. regarding your example before the last, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293521/does-ln-sf-overwrites-existing-files-which-are-only-symbolic-links